# How to convert PowerShell System.Net.Http.Httpclient call to Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, httpclient

I have the following code which is working. But my requirements that I can't use System.Net.Http.Httpclient. I have to convert it to Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post. Following code works fine.

```
# Add the necessary .NET assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Net.Http
# Create the HttpClient client
$client = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Http.Httpclient
$client.BaseAddress = $sasHost; 
$action = '/system/collection';
$stringcontent =  New-Object System.Net.Http.StringContent($json, 
     [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8, "application/json");
$response = $client.PostAsync($action, $stringcontent).Result;
# If it is failed 
if($response.IsSuccessStatusCode -eq $false)
{
    write-host $response.StatusCode -foregroundcolor "Red";
}
```

I tried the following. But it throws an exception. I suspect my conversion is not correct. Because the above code works fine. I don't know how to do it correctly.

```
$url = ($sasHost, $action  -join "");
try
{
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $url -ContentType "application/json" -Body $stringcontent
    write-host "Collection bootstrapping done successfully" -foregroundcolor DarkMagenta -BackgroundColor Green;
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host "Exception: "$_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red;
}
```

> $_.Exception.Message The remote server returned an error: (500)
>   Internal Server Error.

Comment: In the second example, is **$stringcontent** the same `Http.StringContent` object as you showed in the first example, or a "plain" JSON string? The class doesn't exist for me (Windows 10) without loading the assembly.

Comment: Or in other words, if that class needs to be loaded then I wouldn't be sure that the `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet supports it.

Comment: This writeup about invoke-restmethod and utf8 might be what you need.. Might look it over and see: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d795e7d2-dcf1-4323-8e06-8f06ce31a897/bug-invokerestmethod-and-utf8-data?forum=winserverpowershell